# SQL left join on select statements with where clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to make an left join on a select statement like this:

```
select *
from (select * from foo  where rownum <= 10 ) tab1
left join (select sum(total) total,sum(worker) worker from bars  where work_date between tab1.start_date and tab1.end_date ) tab2
on tab1.foo_id=tab2.id
```

and I get the following error:

> oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "tab1"."end_date": invalid identifier

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you specify your where clause, you are saying that you want all records between two specific dates. *However*, the code you typed is interpreted as "I want all dates between the following record set of various dates". It can't handle that. Do you intend for it to be between the earliest and latest dates returned by table 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work:

```
select
   tab1.foo_id
  ,tab1.start_date
  ,tab1.end_date
  ,sum(tab2.total) as total
  ,sum(tab2.worker) as worker
from foo tab1
left join bars tab2
  on tab2.work_date between tab1.start_date and tab1.end_date
  and tab1.foo_id = tab2.id
where tab1.rownum <= 10
group by
   tab1.foo_id
  ,tab1.start_date
  ,tab1.end_date
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do what you want uses two correlated subqueries:

```
select foo.*
     (select sum(b.total) as total, sum(worker) as worker
      from bars
      where b.work_date between foo.start_date and foo.end_date and
            foo.foo_id = b.id
     ) as total,
     (select sum(b.worker) as worker
      from bars b
      where b.work_date between foo.start_date and foo.end_date and
            foo.foo_id = b.id
     ) as worker
from foo
where rownum <= 10;
```

Comment: is really that only one way? actually i found the way you  mention above, i asked here because i think more efficient if i use join because  fewer select query. actually  5 column from bars  which i must select.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur . . . The word "only" does not appear anywhere in my answer.  If you want a more general solution, I would suggest that you ask *another* question and include sample data and desired results.  This question is rather specific and the data is not described (not the version of Oracle), so I will stick by this solution as being the most expedient.